# Is it possible to play mp3 via Azure Media Player, without having an image?

Tags: html, azure, audio

I'm using Azure Blob Storage (not Azure Media Services) to store some `mp4` and `mp3` files, and I can easily show my videos and play my MP3 files.

However, for `mp3` files, it shows an empty screen, which is not the desired behavior. And I really don't want to provide an image for my audio files.

The more I see AMP's documentation, the less I find about how to configure it for audio.

Even its [`mp3` samples](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/samples.html) contain a [default image](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_progressiveAudio.html). Is there a way to hide or not show that image for playing audio files?